# How can I run OneTrust Test Script from Chrome dev console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following script/snippet:

```
<script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="2edd13a2-zx99-5563-brtg-99ddk991476c-test" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OptanonWrapper() { }
</script>
```

How can I run it from Chrome Developer Console for testing purpose? I'd tried to add it as a snippet but I got all kind of error depending of what I'm trying to do.